Angular/TypScript: Create type for Form based on Model
I have a model like this:
interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  gender: 'male' | 'female';
}

I want a generic way to create the type of a Angular-Form based on this model. My first approach:
export type ModelForm<T> = FormGroup<{
  [K in keyof T]: FormControl<T[K]>;
}>

I can do type my UserModelForm like this const myForm: ModelForm<User> and everything is correct.
But what if my Model has Arrays and Objects in it. For Example:
interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  gender: 'male' | 'female';
  validity: {
    validFrom: Date,
    validUntil: Date | null,
  }
  addresses: {street: string, houseNumber:number}[],
}

How can I handle this?

Here is the solution for your answer although it is not recommended due to complexity of the types that it requires for understanding.
1, T[K] extends (infer U) means if the instance is array of some kind then take it as fromArray
2, T[K] extends object means if the instance is object then it might be formGroup or formControl.
type CustomType<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (infer U)[]
  ? FormArray<FormControl<U> | FormGroup<CustomType<U>>>
  : T[K] extends object
  ? FormGroup<CustomType<T[K]>>
  : FormControl<T[K]>;
};


The solution I have come up with involves a chain of ternary if else conditions, each applying the FormControl/ FormGroup / FormArray based on the datatype of the interface, it's not flawless but it's a good starting point to help you solve the issue of adding FormControl for complex interfaces.
export type ModelFormComplex<T> = FormGroup<{
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Date ? FormControl<T[K]> : 
                  T[K] extends String ? FormControl<T[K]> : 
                  T[K] extends number ? FormControl<T[K]> : 
                  T[K] extends boolean ? FormControl<T[K]> : 
                  T[K] extends Array<object> ? FormArray<ModelFormComplex<T[K][0]>> : 
                  T[K] extends object ? ModelFormComplex<T[K]> : FormControl<T[K]>;

Full Code:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormControl,
  AbstractControl,
  FormArray,
} from '@angular/forms';
interface User {
  firstName: string | null;
  lastName: string | null;
  gender: 'male' | 'female';
}
export type ModelForm<T> = FormGroup<{
  [K in keyof T]: FormControl<T[K]>;
}>;
// export type ModelFormComplex<T> = FormGroup<{
//   [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Array<object> ? FormArray<ModelForm<T[K]>> : T[K] extends object ? ModelForm<T[K]> : FormControl<T[K]>;
// }>;
    export type ModelFormComplex<T> = FormGroup<{
      [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Date ? FormControl<T[K]> : 
                      T[K] extends String ? FormControl<T[K]> : 
                      T[K] extends number ? FormControl<T[K]> : 
                      T[K] extends boolean ? FormControl<T[K]> : 
                      T[K] extends Array<object> ? FormArray<ModelFormComplex<T[K][0]>> : 
                      T[K] extends object ? ModelFormComplex<T[K]> : FormControl<T[K]>;
}>;
interface Address {
  street: string; 
  houseNumber: number;
}
interface UserComplex {
  firstName: string | null;
  lastName: string | null;
  gender: 'male' | 'female';
  validity: {
    validFrom: Date;
    validUntil: Date | null;
  };
  addresses: Address[];
}
export type ModelFormAddress = ModelFormComplex<Address>;
export type ModelFormUser = ModelFormComplex<User>;
export type ModelFormUserComplex = ModelFormComplex<UserComplex>;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `asdf123`,
})
export class App {
  form1: ModelFormUser = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
    gender: new FormControl<'male' | 'female'>('male', {
      nonNullable: true,
    }),
  });
  form2: ModelFormUserComplex = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
    gender: new FormControl<'male' | 'female'>('male', {
      nonNullable: true,
    }),
    validity: new FormGroup({
      validFrom: new FormControl(new Date(), {
        nonNullable: true,
      }),
      validUntil: new FormControl(new Date()),
    }),
    addresses: new FormArray<ModelFormAddress>([]),
  });
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
